# How to use #pragma comment(linker) to add *.obj files? VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors

If i add *.obj file at Project >> Properties >> Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies += FileName.obj - it is OK.

How do it in source file?

I can add file *.lib:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "FileName.lib")
```

BUT i can't add file *.obj:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/DEFAULTLIB:FileName.obj")
```

warning LNK4003: invalid library format; library ignored

comment (C/C++) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx

My goal is to write tests for project ConsoleApplication(exe).

I want to link the tests to the object file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh419385.aspx

Comment: And if you leave off the `/DEFAULTLIB:` switch?

Comment: You tell the linker 'hey here's a library' then give it an object file, those are 2 different things..

Comment: if i add *.obj file at Project >> Properties >> Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies += FileName.obj - it is OK

Comment: How do it in source file?